# Is std::list<>::sort stable?

Tags: c++, sorting, stl

I couldn't find any definitive answer to this question.

I suppose most implementation use merge sort that is stable but, is the stability a requirement or a side effect?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

C++ Standard ISO/IEC 14882:2003 says:

> 23.2.2.4/31
>
> **Notes:** Stable: the relative order of the equivalent elements is preserved. If an exception is thrown the
> order of the elements in the list is indeterminate.

Comment: +1. SGI and Stroustrup are both correct but not the "definitive answer". ISO 14882 is.

Comment: Only great answers but I admit this is the best. ;)

Answer (score 12):

Yes, std::list<>::sort is guaranteed to be stable.

See http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/List.html

Answer (score 10):

According to "The C++ Programming Language" (Stroustrup p470), yes, stl::list<>::sort is stable.