# c++ std::list sort preserve order

Tags: c++, sorting, stdlist

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is std::list<>::sort stable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/609956/is-stdlistsort-stable)

Does C++ std::list sort function is guaranteed to preserve the order of equal elements in the list? E.g. if we have objects A, B and C in the list and the comparison operators are overloaded so that A == C and B < A, will we necessarily get B-A-C or is it possible to get a B-C-A?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100561/stable-sorting-a-stl-list-in-c .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, in C++ `list::sort()` is stable, per ISO 14882:2003 23.2.2.4[lib.list.ops]/31

```
Effects: Sorts the list according to the operator< or a Compare function object.
Notes: Stable: the relative order of the equivalent elements is preserved. 
If an exception is thrown the order of the elements in the list is indeterminate.
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, the standard requires the list::sort to be stable.